# problem with a command on magic 8ball machine

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with Discord.js , right now i'm trying to make a magic 8ball. the problem I'm having is starting the command and up as it wont respond. (I have used the `bot.on('message', message =>` line before in the same file.

I have tried looking around youtube for an 8 ball machine but theirs are quite different. Also i'm quite new to programming

````
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.startsWith(prefix + "8ball") && (message.length() > 10)) {
        let replies = ["Yes.", "No.", "I don't see it happening anytime soon.", "Maybe.", "Maybe....... Not.", "The future looks bright.", "Definitely Yes.", "Please ask again later.", "C'mon man don't put me on the spot like that."];
        let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));
        message.channel.send(result);
    } else {
        message.channel.reply("sorry I dont understand your question");
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

`.length()` is not a function and `message` is an object that contains lots of details instead of just the content. What you wanna do is `message.content.length > 10`
So your code would look something like :

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.startsWith(`${prefix}8ball`) && (message.content.length > 10)) {
        let replies = ["Yes.", "No.", "I don't see it happening anytime soon.", "Maybe.", "Maybe....... Not.", "The future looks bright.", "Definitely Yes.", "Please ask again later.", "C'mon man don't put me on the spot like that."];
        let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));
        message.channel.send(result);
    } else {
        message.channel.reply("sorry I dont understand your question");
    }
});
```

Also notice I changed `prefix + '8ball'` to `${prefix}8ball`. The ${} notation allows you to place stuff directly within the string instead of having to concatenate them every single time.